# multiple objects on the same plot (MATPLOTLIB)

Tags: python, matplotlib, drawing, multiple-instances

SHORT QUESTION:
I'd like to draw different shapes using winged egde strucutre, so I have one class that actually draw any winged eged and another to define a cube and other shapes. Now I want to draw 2 cubes on the same figure but I can't and I always get one cube in each figure.

LONG QUESTION:
I'd like to draw different shapes using winged egde strucutre, so I have:

```
class WEdge -> wedge_instance = WEdge(vertices, faces)
```

and then I have one class for each shape that I need to draw for example:

```
class Box -> simplebox = Box(vertices, faces, translation, rotation)
```

In the WEdge class I actually plot the objects using the following code:

```
        ax = a3.Axes3D(pl.figure())
        for k in range(self.nFaces):
           currentColumn = self.faces[k,:]
           vtx = np.zeros([4,3])
           j = 0
           for i in currentColumn:
               vtx[j] = self.vertices[i-1]
               j = j +1
        tri = a3.art3d.Poly3DCollection([vtx])
        tri.set_color(colors.rgb2hex(sp.rand(3)))
        tri.set_edgecolor('b')
        ax.add_collection3d(tri)
```

The problem is when I want to draw two cube in the same figure. I have tried many possible combinations of hold, gca and so on but in the end I get always one cube in Figure 1 and the other in Figure 2.

Example:

```
>>>Box(3,1,3, [0,1,0], np.eye(3))
>>> # hold, gca, timer...
>>>Box(3,1,3, [1,0,3], np.eye(3))
```

[image: Box(3,1,3, [0,1,0], np.eye(3)][image: Box(3,1,3, [1,0,3], np.eye(3)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't define a new axis for each "structure":

```
    ax = a3.Axes3D(pl.figure())
```

Pass `ax` into the `WEdge` class, so they can all draw on the same axis:

```
def init(self, ..., ax=None):
    self.ax = ax if ax else a3.Axes3D(pl.figure())

we1 = WEdge()
we2 = WEdge(ax=we1.ax)
```

or perhaps more egalitarian,

```
ax = a3.Axes3D(pl.figure())
we1 = WEdge(ax)
we2 = WEdge(ax)
```

You may need to also pass `ax` to your cube class too.